# Advanced custom field as CSS class

Tags: php, css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using WordPress with ACF, I need to use a custom field as the width of a CSS class.

I created a dynamic style with a variable:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css"); 
$scala = get_field('scala');  
?>

#chart li .bar {    
height: 10px;
background: #546a79;
width: <?php echo  $scala  ; ?> }
```

Unfortunately I can not see the result on the page, But if I put a precise value then it's works:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css"); 
$scala = '60%';  
?>

#chart li .bar {    
height: 10px;
background: #546a79;
width: <?php echo  $scala  ; ?> }
```

Obviously I already have registered the custom value in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you add a custom class to the container of the content that you want to scale with a custom field on the post. Soemthing like a dropdown that you can set to "sixty" perhaps and then have the following code:

```
<div class="post-container <?php the_field('sixty'); ?>">
```

which will make the  div  look like this, when the class is activated:

```
 <div class="post-container sixty">
```

And then style it like this:

```
.post-container.sixty {
  width: 60%
}
```